# Can I hang drywall from strapping on an open slanted ceiling?

Tags: drywall, framing, ceiling

I want to close in the open shed ceiling in my living room/dining room.

The beams are 4x8 on 32" centers. Can I run 1x3 strapping across the beams parallel every 24" or 16"? Would this be enough to support drywall? I may end up having the ceiling plastered (undecided) since the walls are all plaster and the hallway ceiling is plaster. I'm not sure if this adds a weight concern.

The reason is I had some leaks and the soft material under the roof ply is bad, instead of trying to pull off the rubber roof & ply around the chimney and match the materiaL from the 50'S. I'm just going to close it off which also lets me solve the poor lighting situation in that room by installing recessed lighting at the same time. [image] [image]

Comment: pictures would help understand your situation.  Are you sure the beams are structural?

Comment: Thanks, I added pictures.

Comment: @RMDman as for structural, I don't know. They support the roof.

Comment: Have the leaks been repaired?

Comment: @ Huesmann, I'm in the process of having that done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly support a ceiling that way, but I doubt 1x3 spanning 32" is going to be enough - you'll probably need 2x3, (or a metal support rated for the span) at minimum.

I'd suggest adding more insulation at the same time.

Comment: And in case folks don't know, it is _definitely_ worth renting a wallboard jack when doing ceilings. Yes, you can get by with more assistants and T braces, and I've done it that way, but having the jack lift and brace while you just drive screws is a LOT less work.

Comment: I can use 2x3 or even 2x4. I added some photos above. @Keshlam I will definitely rent or buy a drywall lift.

Comment: Yeah, a panel lift really makes it "Do it **Yourself**" rather than "Do it when you can rope in enough helpers, but before they get too inebriated" (because you really need a bribe to get helpers...)

Comment: Quite true, @Ecnerwal, however, the bribe can be handed out in _very_ small quantities before the work starts and _liberally_ once the work has been completed. ;)

Comment: Looking at the picture I added above. Does it look like drywall is feasible if I run 2x3 or 2x4 on 16" centers? Anything else I need to be concerned with?

Comment: The actual open span between beams is 28-1/4" with 32" centers.

Comment: Yes, your verbal description was clear to me, 2x3 or 2x4 should work fine for that span/center distance.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, Thank You.